# How do i compare if my variable holds a newline character in shell Script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script in which I have a line which does put the third line fetched in my variable like this:

```
variable=`sed -n '3 p' /home/nmsadm/abc.txt`
```

So `variable` holds this value Which is in third line of abc.txt. In my case it 
will be a one word line or an empty/blank line.

How can I compare the variable in a shell script to know if it's an empty/blank line? 
`echo $variable` fetched me an empty line.

What is the comparison i need to here so that
I am assured it's an empty line? Something like this:

```
if [ "$variable" = "comparison" ]; then
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Empty or undefined:

```
if [ -z "${variable-}" ]
```

Single newline:

```
if [ "${variable-}" = $'\n' ]
```

Undefined:

```
if [ "${variable+defined}" != defined ]
```

Note, the last command is *not* the opposite of

```
if [ "${variable-undefined}" = undefined ]
```

To see why, try running `variable=undefined` first. `"${variable+defined}"` has only two possible values: The empty string or `defined`.

Comment: +1. you only need to check for empty because command substitution (the backticks) will strip off any trailing newlines (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

Answer (score 3):

```
read str
if [ ${#str} -eq 0 ]       #this can been used to decide whether str is empty or not 
   then
        echo "empty"
else
    echo "not empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The below command will store the length of the variable in var_length.

`var_length=$(echo ${#variable})`

if $var_length is greater than or equal to 1, $variable is a string

Comment: Or just `var_length=${#variable}`