# how to determine a newline in bash?

Tags: bash, sh, newline

A file:

```
a
b
```

run command

```
dd if=file count=1 skip=0 bs=1 # show a
dd if=file count=1 skip=1 bs=1 # show "newline"
dd if=file count=1 skip=2 bs=1 # show b
```

I want to search the offset of the first "newline" before a given offset, with 'if' statement in a bash script (which is a dummy way):

```
para1=$1
while(1)
do
    c=$(dd if=file count=1 bs=1 skip=$para1)
    if [ $c -eq "\n" ]   # How to write this line?
    then
        break
    fi
    para1=`expo $para - 1`
done
echo $para1
```

```
bash fun.sh 2
# the output should be 1
```

Actually I have found a solution   here:[How do i compare if my variable holds a newline character in shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974109/how-do-i-compare-if-my-variable-holds-a-newline-character-in-shell-script)

```
if [ ${#str} -eq 0 ]
```

But I wonder is it robust enough, or is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your task: what's a "newline offset", what's the "given offset", what do you mean by "reversely"? Notice that the `$` is only to illustrate a linebreak. It's not really there.

Comment: for example: a file with "1234567", the offset of "1" is 0, the offset of "3" is 2, given the offset 2, I need to search "7" reversely, so there is none, but if I need to search "1" reversely, the found offset is 0. "$" did take a character. Use "dd skip=xxx count=1 bs=1" you can find a gap between the last char of line and the first char of the next line @BenjaminW.

Comment: Would something like `awk` do? Ex. `awk -v ndx=3 'sum+length($0) < ndx {sum+=length($0); next} {print sum; exit}' file` where the value of `ndx` is the character in the file you are looking for and the character number of the newline prior to the index is the result? (`1` in this case). Or given the file containing `"hello\nworld\nthis\nis\na\ntest\n"` and `ndx=12` (the `'h'` in `"this"`), the result is `10` (the newline before `'t'`)

Comment: The only place where `$` means newline is in regular expressions. I don't see how that's relevant to this task.

Comment: `$( )` always trims any newlines at the end of what it reads, so the result will *never* match `\n` or `\r\n`. One way around this is to add a protective non-newline at the end, then remove it: `c=$(dd if=file count=1 bs=1 skip=$para1; echo x); c=${c%x}`. Also, for the test, `-eq` does numeric comparisons, not string comparison. Also, comparing to `"\n"` will compare to a literal backslash followed by the letter "n", *not* a newline. For a newline, use `$'\n'`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Your description is bravo. But  ```c=$(dd if=file count=1 bs=1 skip=$para1; echo x); c=${c%x}``` doesn't work. It's still tried. Besides, ```$( )``` will also trim whitespace, is there a proper way to find the $'\n'?

Comment: @YNX It works in my tests. The `dd ...; echo x` part prints `<newline>x<newline>`, the `$( )` removes the final newline leaving `<newline>x`, and the `%x` removes the "x" from the end leaving just a newline. After that, testing `[ "$c" = $'\n' ]` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please focus on the code:

```
c=$(dd if=test1 skip=2 bs=1 count=1)
```

The Command Substitution section of `man bash` describes:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command  ... with any trailing newlines deleted.

Because of this the newline in the result of `dd` command above is removed.
You'll see it by the test code below:

```
for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ )); do
    c="$(dd if=test1 skip="$i" bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)"
    echo "skip = $i"
    echo -n "$c" | xxd
done
```

In general `bash` is not suitable for explicitly dealing with the newline
character
because bash sometimes automatically removes or adds it.

If `perl` is your option, please try the following:

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    $given = 3;     # an example of the given offset
    printf "character at offset %d = %s\n", $given, substr($_, $given, 1);
    $pos = rindex(substr($_, 0, $given), "\n", $given);
    if ($pos < 0) {
        print "not found\n";
    } else {
        printf "newline found at offset %d\n", $given - $pos - 1;
    }
' file
```

If you prefer `bash`, here is the alternative in bash:

```
file="./file"
given=3                               # an example of the given offset

str="$(xxd -ps "$file" | tr -d '\n')" # to the hexadecimal expression
for (( i=given; i>=0; i-- )); do
    j=$(( i * 2 ))
    c="${str:$j:2}"                   # substring offset j, length 2
    if [[ $c = "0a" ]]; then          # search for the substring "0a"
        printf "newline found at offset %d\n" $(( given - i - 1 ))
        exit
    fi
done
echo "not found"
```

The concept is same as the perl version. It first converts the whole file into the hexadecimal expression and searches for the substring "0a" starting at the given position backwards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a bash alternative. Please enjoy!